# How can i optimise this JS code to avoid the repetition of assigning different API values to different element?

Tags: javascript

So I am kinda new to JS and I have been trying to fetch data from the API server but as you can see each currency element is assigned to a different coin value. I have also tried using for loop for the currency object but am unable to avoid this repetition.

```
const container=document.querySelector(".scoll_display");
const currency=container.querySelectorAll(".Exchange_rate");

async function getExchangePrice() {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "x-cg-demo-api-key": "CG-NhdhrCZRnCSqdjMyf3XUu9k4" },
    };
  
    try {
        const response1= await fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchange_rates", options);
        const data1 = await response1.json();
        
        currency[1].innerHTML=`(ETH) ${data1.rates.eth.value}`;
        currency[2].innerHTML=`(LTC) ${data1.rates.ltc.value}`;
        currency[3].innerHTML=`(BCH) ${data1.rates.bch.value}`;
        currency[4].innerHTML=`(BNB) ${data1.rates.bnb.value}`;
        currency[5].innerHTML=`(XLM) ${data1.rates.xlm.value}`;
        currency[6].innerHTML=`(DOT) ${data1.rates.dot.value}`;
        currency[7].innerHTML=`(₹) ${data1.rates.inr.value}`;
        currency[8].innerHTML=`(¥) ${data1.rates.jpy.value}`;
        currency[9].innerHTML=`(μBTC) ${data1.rates.bits.value}`;
        currency[10].innerHTML=`(£) ${data1.rates.gbp.value}`; 
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  
  getExchangePrice();
```

Comment: I believe data1.rates should be an array, so you could use a "forEach" on it to set your HTML content.  If you only want certain rates returned via the API call, then you may be able set an appropriate filter on the API call?

Comment: You say you "tried a loop", but you think it didn't meet your needs - it might be more useful to show what looping you tried, and why you think it's not working as you'd expect, then others can help guide you with that.  After all, StackOverflow is meant to be all about HELPING YOU achieve your desired outcome, not necessarily just someone doing the work for you

Comment: How do you decide which scroll_container so which rate?

Comment: @Craig `data1.rates` is an object

Comment: @brk yes data1 will look like this:```{
  "rates": {
    "btc": {
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "unit": "BTC",
      "value": 1,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "eth": {
      "name": "Ether",
      "unit": "ETH",
      "value": 19.414,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "ltc": {
      "name": "Litecoin",
      "unit": "LTC",
      "value": 771.956,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "bch": {
      "name": "Bitcoin Cash",
      "unit": "BCH",
      "value": 144.17,
      "type": "crypto"
    },........```

Comment: Array index starts from `0`. So, I believe you should be using `currency[0].innerHTML` to `currency[9].innerHTML`. Or, is there any specific reason that you are starting from `currency[1].innerHTML`?

Comment: @Craig I am new to both programming and the platform itself, Thanks for the useful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `forEach` in this case to avoid repitetion:

1. declare array of currency:

```
const currencyTypes=['eth','ltc','bth'....etc] ;
```

2. forEach loop:

```
 currencyTypes.forEach((type, index) => {
            currency[index + 1].innerHTML = `(${type.toUpperCase()}) ${data.rates[type].value}`;
        });
```

if you want all currency data in that case no need of declaring the currencyTypes variable you can directly do it:

````
Object.keys(data.rates).forEach((type, index) => {
            currency[index + 1].innerHTML = `(${data.rates[type].unit}) ${data.rates[type].value}`;
        });```
````

Comment: Your answer will work well. +1. I'm suggesting minor improvements. Since, as per question you can see symbols can be different than currency code in upper case. So, instead of using `const currencyTypes=['eth','ltc','bth'....etc];`, you can use `array of objects` like `const currencyTypes=[{type: 'eth', symbol: 'ETH'}, ...];` and do necessary changes inside `forEach`.

Comment: @Karan right if he wants the all the data then we could use Object.keys(data1.rates) which returns arrays

Comment: Note that using `object.keys` as suggested would assign element `innerHTML` properties in the order the property keys were assigned to the `rates` object. This could be acceptable but could also differ from existing requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how many currencies you want you can add the data attribute into your element and create a function to paste the each of the value into the element like below.

```js
let data = {
  rates : {
      eth: 4000,
      btc: 2000,
      idr: 3000,
      myr: 2000
  }
};

let pasteCurrency = (currency, value) => {
let el =  document.querySelector('.currency[data-currency="'+ currency +'"]');
  el.innerHTML = `${currency} ${value}`;
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data.rates)) {
  pasteCurrency(key, value);
}
```

```html
<div class="currency" data-currency="eth"></div>
<div class="currency" data-currency="btc"></div>
<div class="currency" data-currency="idr"></div>
<div class="currency" data-currency="myr"></div>
```

If you want to parse based on the return data, it can be done as well by modifying the pasteCurrency above to be insertion into your currency exchange.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid writing out individual assignments to elements' `innerHTML`, the rate property names and abbreviation need to be encoded in the code so they can be accessed  progaramatically. As an example, you could try replacing

```js
  currency[1].innerHTML=`(ETH) ${data1.rates.eth.value}`;
  currency[2].innerHTML=`(LTC) ${data1.rates.ltc.value}`;
  currency[3].innerHTML=`(BCH) ${data1.rates.bch.value}`;
  currency[4].innerHTML=`(BNB) ${data1.rates.bnb.value}`;
  currency[5].innerHTML=`(XLM) ${data1.rates.xlm.value}`;
  currency[6].innerHTML=`(DOT) ${data1.rates.dot.value}`;
  currency[7].innerHTML=`(₹) ${data1.rates.inr.value}`;
  currency[8].innerHTML=`(¥) ${data1.rates.jpy.value}`;
  currency[9].innerHTML=`(μBTC) ${data1.rates.bits.value}`;
```

with something like

```js
const rates = {
  eth: "ETH",
  ltc: "LTC"
  bch: "BCH"
  bnb: "BNB",
  xlm: "XLM",
  dot: "DOT",
  inr: "₹",
  jpy: "¥",
  bits: "μBTC"
};
Object.entries(rates).forEach( (entry, i) => {
  const {key, value} = entry;
  currency[i+1].innerHTML = `(${value}) ${data.rates[key].value}`;
});
```